# Leontief-like matrix

Tags: matrices

How I can make matrices (similar to a Leontief technology matrix) as shown here?: [image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Have you searched this site for "labels matrix" and "braces matrix"? There is already a lot around here.

Comment: Hi and welcome, adding a MWE helps to understand the problem, and more important, it saves typing.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Why `\documentclass`, why `\end{document}`? There are TeX users they needn't to use `\documentclass` in their document.

Comment: Seems strang, I cannot believe at the moment, that no documentclass is required. But if you can show me an example....

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger Example is: `Hello world.\bye`.

Comment: @wipet The base assumption here is that the document is a LaTeX document unless explicitly stated otherwise.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I disagree with such assumption. Why to manipulate novice users to the badly designed macro package? Why not to assume the plain TeX document unless explicitly stated otherwise? Plain TeX is a base of all another packages.

Comment: @wipet Really a meta discussion, but see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/302/15925 under "Discouraged tags"

Comment: @wipet: I am sorry, but I completely disagree with your statement. Everybody has it's own personal preferences, which is obvious. However, whether you like it or not, nowadays LaTeX is implicit the de facto standard for the majority of the guys. Just compare the queries on google http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=%2Fm%2F04mdr%2C%20%2Fm%2F07dh_&cmpt=q&tz=

Answer (score 4):

You can try to experiment with the following code:

```
$$
  \def\indu{{\rm Industry\ }}
  \hbox{INPUTS } P=\left\{ \matrix{\indu S_1\cr \indu S_2 \cr \dotfill \cr \indu S_n}
    \left[\vcenter{\vbox{\kern-28pt\halign{\hfil#\hfil\cr
       OUTPUTS\cr 
       $\overbrace{\matrix{
          s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & \cdots & s_n \cr 
          a   & b   &  c  & \cdots & d   \cr 
          e   & f   &  g  & \cdots & h   \cr
          \multispan5\dotfill \cr
          u   & w   &  w  & \cdots & z  \cr
       }}$\cr}}}\right]
  \matrix{\sum\indu S_1\cr \sum\indu S_2\cr \dotfill \cr \sum\indu S_n}
  \right.
$$
\bye
```

You can learn how the `\hbox`, `\vbox`, `\vcenter` and `\halign` work. These are basic TeX primitives for typesetting such matrices.

Comment: I will not build a preamble on my own to process your code. If you do not supply a minimal working example than you have to pass my help. It does not feel right, that you are not willing to provide processable code....

Comment: This _is_ minimal working example. This is processable by `tex document` command. Forget LaTeX.

Comment: sorry, you are right.